# most linux commands gives -bash: clear: command not found , after a binary execution (Raspberry pi)

Tags: raspbian, linux, serial

what could be possibly wrong when following dmesg occurs in Raspberry pi
Following is Output of dmesg command,

```
[  227.820110] mmc0: card 0001 removed
[  227.820411] Aborting journal on device mmcblk0p2-8.
[  227.820491] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for mmcblk0p2-8.
[  227.821980] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): I/O error while writing superblock
[  227.822002] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal
[  227.822489] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): I/O error while writing superblock
[  227.831750] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): Remounting filesystem read-only
[  227.832356] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_journal_check_start:61: Detected aborted journal
[  227.838092] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): I/O error while writing superblock
[  228.003401] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.041121] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.065754] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.091936] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.117710] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.142683] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.168877] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.194612] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.218823] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.244164] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm (umount): reading directory lblock 0
[  228.378034] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  228.379636] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  228.382793] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  228.384547] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  228.387745] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  228.389424] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  228.392619] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  228.394300] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  228.397512] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  228.399183] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  233.004492] EXT4-fs error: 11088 callbacks suppressed
[  233.004503] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #24145: comm boot.sh: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.143234] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #64386: comm boot.sh: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.279544] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #64386: comm boot.sh: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.369388] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #2: comm agetty: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.416202] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #10423: comm boot.sh: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.682933] EXT4-fs warning: 2004 callbacks suppressed
[  233.682946] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  233.682989] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #48290: comm boot.sh: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.819465] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #8049: comm boot.sh: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.959088] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #64386: comm boot.sh: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.971287] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #64386: comm boot.sh: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.983151] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #10423: comm boot.sh: reading directory lblock 0
[  233.994726] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  233.998350] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  233.999967] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  234.003352] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  234.005007] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  234.008358] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  234.010522] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  234.014408] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
[  234.016276] EXT4-fs warning (device mmcblk0p2): dx_probe:761: inode #10418: lblock 0: comm boot.sh: error -5 reading directory block
```

**My application tries to read from /dev/ttyAMA0 in raspberry pi, this error occurs and Raspberry pi crashes and no commands work on terminal except cd, once restarted manually Pi works fine, untill re-running the application again.**

Comment: `EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): I/O error while writing superblock` ... dying SD card

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for the Reply,  i am using Raspberry pi 3 compute module, not SD card, and this error occurs only when executing a application. i dont see the error or malfunctioning of console other times.

Comment: dying eMMC if that's where the OS is installed

Comment: could also be filesystem errors on the sd card caused by unplugging the pi power without shutting it down properly.

Comment: @svin83 Thanks for your Reply, but i am using a Compute module, so it is not possible to unplug SD card , it uses eMMC

Comment: I didn't say you unplugged the sd, i said unplugged the power.  Can you boot from USB and do a forced fsck of the filesystem, or alternatively write a new image to the eMMC?

Answer (score 1):

The first error here indicates the problem:

```
[  227.820110] mmc0: card 0001 removed
```

It appears that your mmc card has taken itself offline, likely your root filesystem is no longer available.

There are several possible reasons for this, the most likley is the device is failing.  Possibly when your application runs, it stresses the device enough that the failures cause it to crash.  When your application is not running, the device is idle, so it doesn't crash right away.

Another less likely alternative would be that the bus to the device is crashing, and something in the application is interfering with or stressing the bus to the device.

Comment: Thanks @user10489 for your help, what you have mentioned was the issue, same application runs well in different board.